# Struct pointer strange behavior

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, linked-list, gdb

I'm trying to make a BrainFuck (BF) interpreter using a two-way linked list. However, the way I'm moving through this list seems to have a rather strange impact on cells.

So first here's the part of my program that gives me a hard time

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Cell c = {NULL, NULL, '\0', NULL};
    Cell* codeCell = &c;
    Cell b = {NULL, NULL, '\0', NULL};
    Cell* bandCell = &b;

    //init
    bandCell->val = '\0';
    bandCell->firstCell = bandCell;

    codeCell->firstCell = codeCell;

    //get code
    printf("BF code : ");
    codeCell->val=getchar();
    while(codeCell->val != '\n') {
        if(
            codeCell->val=='<'||codeCell->val=='>'
            ||codeCell->val=='+'||codeCell->val=='-'
            ||codeCell->val=='['||codeCell->val==']'
            ||codeCell->val==','||codeCell->val=='.'
        ) {
            newCell(codeCell)->val = getchar();
            codeCell = codeCell->nextCell;
        }
        else {
            codeCell->val = getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

The Cell struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct Cell Cell;
struct Cell {
    Cell* precCell;
    Cell* nextCell;
    char val;
    Cell* firstCell;
};
```

And the function `Cell* newCell(Cell*)` like this:

```
Cell* newCell (Cell* precCell) {
    Cell n = {precCell, NULL, '\0', precCell->firstCell};
    Cell* newCell = &n;
    precCell->nextCell = newCell;
    return newCell;
}
```

In this I try to get user input char by char and put it in a cell only if it's a correct BF instruction.
I ended up having a `SEGFAULT` so I tried to find the source of it and I think it comes from this strange behaviour at line 42: when I try to update the `val` of the newly created cell with whatever is in the `getchar()` buffer, the cell `codeCell->nextCell` loose all its values but I'm sure it's the same cell because the address is still the same. You can see in the following example from GDB the test of what I just said.

```
BF code : .

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x742278) at bf_debug_test.c:42
42                              newCell(codeCell)->val = getchar();
(gdb) s
newCell (precCell=0x28ff18) at bf_debug_test.c:13
13              Cell n = {precCell, NULL, '\0', precCell->firstCell};
(gdb)
14              Cell* newCell = &n;
(gdb)
15              precCell->nextCell = newCell;
(gdb)
16              return newCell;
(gdb) p precCell
$1 = (Cell *) 0x28ff18
(gdb) p *precCell
$2 = {precCell = 0x0, nextCell = 0x28fed4, val = 46 '.', firstCell = 0x28ff18}
(gdb) p newCell
$3 = (Cell *) 0x28fed4
(gdb) p *newCell
$4 = {precCell = 0x28ff18, nextCell = 0x0, val = 0 '\000',
  firstCell = 0x28ff18}
(gdb) s
17      }
(gdb)
main (argc=1, argv=0x742278) at bf_debug_test.c:43
43                              codeCell = codeCell->nextCell;
(gdb) p codeCell
$5 = (Cell *) 0x28ff18
(gdb) p *codeCell
$6 = {precCell = 0x0, nextCell = 0x28fed4, val = 46 '.', firstCell = 0x28ff18}
(gdb) p codeCell->nextCell
$7 = (Cell *) 0x28fed4
(gdb) p *codeCell->nextCell
$8 = {precCell = 0x76ad7220 <msvcrt!_local_unwind4+464>,
  nextCell = 0x1d6aff2c, val = 10 '\n',
  firstCell = 0x76acf24c <msvcrt!getc+188>}
```

I hope this is enough informations to understand my problem,
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you edit to include `newcell`, or, better, a [mcve]?

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a `Cell` object allocated on the stack. As soon as `newCell()` returns, that function's stack frame is cleaned up and that object no longer exists. You need to allocate your `Cell` objects on the heap using `malloc()`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to put the pointer in a variable like this ?
`Cell* n = newCell(codeCell);
n->val = getchar();
`

Comment: @Tix'at No. If `newCell()` is just returning a pointer to a local variable, that variable isn't going to exist anymore once `newCell()` returns. The only function-local variables that continue to exist after the function returns are those declared as `static`. However, even that wouldn't work, because you'd just be returning a pointer to the same object every time, instead of creating a new one each time. If you want `newCell` to actually *create* a new cell each time it is called (as it's name implies), you need to allocate memory each time. No way around that.

Comment: @Tix'at I'd start by understanding what a stack is (a.k.a. a "call stack"), and then look up the difference between stack memory allocation and heap memory allocation (e.g., search for "stack vs heap").

Comment: Oh I understand now why my cell seemed to vanish. Thanks a lot for your time :D

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that, thanks :)

Comment: @Tix'at You're welcome.